# Struts 2.0 - getting mutiple datas through model driven

Tags: struts2, model-driven

I have jsp page with following details

`<s:form>`

Enter fname: 
Enter lname:

**Address1:**

Enter City: 
Enter Pin:

**Address2:**

Enter City: 
Enter Pin:

**Address3:**

Enter City: 
Enter Pin:

`</s:form>`

Now i need to fetch all the entries into a single DTO object using the model driven feature.

But how can i get mutiple entries of address fields. The DTO class will contain same for each address fields ie city and pin. Eg: the DTO class will look like :

```
public class Details {

String fname;
String lname;
String city;
String pin;

public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}
public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}
public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}
public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getPin() {
    return pin;
}
public void setPin(String pin) {
    this.pin = pin;
}
}
```

Or i can get them only if i use

```
String[] city;
String[] pin;
```

Also what should of the name of input tag be. Will it be

```
<input type="text" name="city" /> for all city entries
```

or

Is there any other option to get the multiple entries.

Comment: You should use indexed properties of your model.

Comment: just now when i tried using
        String[] city;
        String[] pin;  am getting the contents

Comment: but it doesn't map fields properly.

Answer (score 2):

If we suppose that your form looks like this:

```
public class MyForm {
    private List<Details> addresses;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;

    public List<Details> getAddresses() {
        return this.addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(List<Details> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    /*

    getters and setters for fname and lname properties;    

    */
}
```

and your action, which is implementing `ModelDriven` looks like this:

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<MyForm> {
     private MyForm myForm = new MyForm();

     public String execute() {
          /*

          ....


          */
     }

     @Override
     public MyForm getModel() {
          return this.myform;
     }
}
```

in your JSP file you can set these values as follow:

`<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>`
`<s:form action="your_action" method="post">`

Enter fname: `<s:textfield name="fname"/>`
Enter lname: `<s:textfield name="lname"/>`

Address1:

Enter City: `<s:textfield name="addresses[0].city"/>`
Enter Pin:  `<s:textfield name="addresses[0].pin"/>`

Address2:

Enter City: `<s:textfield name="addresses[1].city"/>`
Enter Pin:  `<s:textfield name="addresses[1].pin"/>`

Address3:

Enter City: `<s:textfield name="addresses[2].city"/>`
Enter Pin:  `<s:textfield name="addresses[2].pin"/>`

`</s:form>`